# How do I write an Indicator for budgie-desktop

Tags: indicator, panel, budgie

I have recently installed the budgie-remix distro of 16.04.2 on my desktop. Works fine, except that I want to build a gtk appindicator for dictionary search, but it does not show up in the budgie indicator panel.

I know that an Application indicator applet support has been extended to budgie, available [here on github](https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/budgie-indicator-applet).

What I want is to write the code to make the indicator show up in the budgie panel itself, rather than relying on the appindicator applet mentioned above. What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

budgie-desktop allows for widgets to be created for the panel to be written in Vala, C and Python.

It is a libpeas based API and the API is very straightfoward.  On GitHub there is an [examples based project](https://github.com/budgie-desktop/budgie-desktop-examples) for Vala, C and Python.

1. Wrap a bit of code around Budgie.Plugin which extends do_get_panel_widget.  This function returns an instance of your widget
2. The widget extends Budgie.Applet
3. The widget/applet can be any GTK based container - typically a button

Have a look at the [python example](https://github.com/budgie-desktop/budgie-desktop-examples/blob/master/python_project/pyshowdesktop.py) as this is the simplest to read.

---

All Peas type plugins consist of a .plugin file and the source.

For budgie-desktop, plugin can be installed in a global location or a local location.

For a local (per user basis), both the .plugin and all source files should be places in `~/.local/share/budgie-desktop/plugins/plugin-name`

For global installation, the .plugin and source module should be installed in `/usr/lib/budgie-desktop/plugins/plugin-name`.  For data based files `/usr/share/budgie-desktop/plugins/plugin-name` is the correct location.

---

budgie-desktop v10.x supports panel widgets. Raven cannot be modified by additional widgets.

It is proposed that in a future version of budgie-desktop that additional widget types can be created.  What form these will take place will be only known as budgie-desktop evolves.

Comment: Running the pyshowdesktop.py file did nothing for me. No indicators on the panel. What am I missing?

Comment: @Razor - updated indicating what is the structure of a plugin and where it is installed

Comment: Thanks a lot. Anything on the Raven sidebar applets? (see question edit)

Comment: @Razor - answer updated